# Which purana to follow?

Tags: puranas

There is so much confusion  shiva Purana says shiva is god, visnu purana says visnu is god which purana to follow who is right? Help me

Comment: follow your elders (parents, grandparents, purohit)

Comment: they are atheists now what to do?

Comment: do ishta devata (favorite deity) nama japa

Comment: The Vedas say Indra and Agni are god. Also, there are puranas which state that Ganesh and Shakti are god. :)